# Issuing with ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

I am having a problem with ParametricNDSolveValue[] . let me start with a simple example. Considered following example with constant parameter $a$.

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], 
   y[0] == a}, y, {x, 0, 30}, {a}]
```

Plot the solutions for several different values of the parameter gives:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pfun[a][t], {a, -1, 1, .1}]], {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now, consider the following case:

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], 
   y[a] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}, {a}]
```

and trying to plot the function I end up with following error "Cannot find starting value for the variable".

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pfun[a][t], {a, -1, 1, .1}]], {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

> ```
> ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable y. >>    
> ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable y. >>    
> ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable y. >>    
> General::stop: Further output of ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsv will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
> ```

I will appreciate for any solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you have noted placing the parameter on the left hand side of a boundary condition:

```
y[b] == 1
```

does not work. You are forced to keep the parameter on the right hand side.

```
y[0] == a
```

What can be done is to keep the parameter on the **RHS** and then use numerical methods to determine the value of `b` for a particular `a` parameter (in other words, seek a relationship between `a` and `b`).

First solve the `ParametricNDSolveValue` using `a` as the parameter.

```
pfunRHS = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  {
   y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]],
   y[0] == a
   },
  y,
  {x, 0, 30},
  {a}
  ]
```

Next, define a function that produces a number when given a parameter value and an `x` coordinate.

```
y[x_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[pfunRHS][a][x]
```

Here is a plot in the interval zero to one for various `a` values.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[t, a], {a, -1, 1, .1}]], {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What we have to do is select a value for the `a` parameter and than solve for the corresponding `b` value where `y[b,a]=1`. Graphically this is where the black line intersects equal contours of `a`.

```
Show[
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[t, a],
    {a, 0.5, 1, .05}]], {t, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> All],
 ListLinePlot[{{0, 1}, {1.1, 1}},
  PlotStyle -> Black]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that below a certain `a` parameter threshold (approximately 0.85) there is no solution.

Given an `a` we can use `FindRoot` to determine the corresponding `b`. Here are two values.

```
FindRoot[
 {
  a - 1,
  y[b, a] - 1
  },
 {{a, 1}, {b, 0.8}}
 ]
(* {a -> 1., b -> 0.978505} *)

FindRoot[
  {a - 0.9,
   y[b, a] - 1
   },
  {{a, 1}, {b, 0.8}}
  ]
(* {a -> 0.9, b -> 0.855604} *)
```

If one tries `a = 0.8` you get an error.

About the lowest one can go is 0.85 for `a`.

```
FindRoot[
 {a - 0.85,
  y[b, a] - 1
  },
 {{a, 0.85}, {b, 0.8}}
 ]
(* {a -> 0.85, b -> 0.735357} *)
```

Superimpose the three points on the plot

```
Show[
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[t, a], {a, 0.5, 1, .05}]], {t, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All],
 ListLinePlot[{{0, 1}, {1.1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Black],
 ListPlot[{{0.975, 1}, {0.8556, 1}, {0.735357, 1}},
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize -> Large, Red}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Create a function to retrieve the `b` value given an `a` value.

```
getB[aStart_?NumericQ] := Module[
  {
   sol
   },
  sol = FindRoot[
    {a - aStart,
     y[b, a] - 1
     },
    {{a, aStart}, {b, 0.8}}
    ];
  sol[[2, 2]]
  ]
```

Plot `b` vs `a`

```
Show[
 Plot[getB[a], {a, 0.85, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Black,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 4.1}, {0, 2}}
  ],
 ListPlot[{
   {0.85, getB[0.85]}, {1, getB[1]},
   {2, getB[2]}, {3, getB[3]}, {4, getB[4]}
   },
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize -> Large, Red}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I didn't want to introduce a diversion but the range of `a` that works has an upper limit as well, around 4.

It may be, depending upon your actual problem, you may be able to develop a functional relationship between `a` and `b` from the numerical results.

Comment: LaVigen  Thanks a lot for you professional answer.